# Maven war file is imported as dynamic web project

Tags: eclipse, maven, web, import, export

I created a maven project (test1) in eclipse EE (2021-09) and added nothing, i.e. accepted the pom and xml files as is and kept the index.jsp file. Choosing run on server, the 'Hello World!' message is displayed.  Then I,

1. exported test1 to a war file
2. renamed the project to 'test1xxx'
3. imported the war file (File>Import>Web>War file)
   The import is no longer a maven project, but a dynamic web app, which runs on the server, but which will not install or run after configuring as a maven project.
   I thought that importing a maven generated war file would result in a maven project.  What am I missing?

Comment: The war file is the deployable artifact which is usually deployed into tomcat or alike but it's not for consumption in your IDE intended...

Comment: If I understand correctly, the Import option on the eclipse File menu is for importing existing projects (i.e. folders containing .classpath and pom.xml files), but a war file would need to be deployed to the server by some other method, such a with a command line utility.

Comment: Yes exactly correctly described. The WAR file is the produced artifact which is not consumable for Eclipse or any other IDE...

Comment: As a follow up question.  What is the purpose of eclipse's Import > Web > War file?

Comment: To be honest I simply don't know..last time I used Eclipse is 4 years ago...my assumption is to deploy to an integrated tomcat (tomcat plugin in Eclipse If I correctly remember)...